# Is it possible to pass XML stream as parameter to XSLT?

Tags: .net, xml, xslt

I have following problem that in a transformation (which is completely done in memory) should recieve an additional XSLT parameter containing another XML stream. 
It's like merging two XML documents together in memory. Writing it down on the drive and load it dynamically is not a possibility.

To develop I use .Net together with Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with .NET (i've tested 4.0). It worked with following code:

C#:

```
XslCompiledTransform proc = new XslCompiledTransform();
proc.Load(path + "test_parameter.xslt");

System.IO.TextWriter result = new StreamWriter(path + "result.html");

XmlDocument docA = new XmlDocument();
docA.Load(path + "documentA.xml");

XmlDocument docB = new XmlDocument();
docB.Load(path + "documentB.xml");

XsltArgumentList xsltArgs = new XsltArgumentList();
xsltArgs.AddParam("xmlDoc", "", docB);

proc.Transform(docA, xsltArgs, result);
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- THIS FILE GENERATES A SIMPLE HTML  -->
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:param name="xmlDoc" />    

  <xsl:template match="/document">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="$xmlDoc/foo/bar"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Note that `System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument` is the preferred tree implementation for XslCompiledTransform so consider using XPathDocument, not XmlDocument for the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Well which programming language, which XSLT processor do you use? What kind of parameters an XSLT processor takes is processor dependent, for instance with .NET's XslCompiledTransform you could certainly define a global parameter in your XSLT code and then use the XsltArgumentList to pass in an IXPathNavigable (i.e. XmlDocument or XPathDocument) created from your stream.

Comment: I would think most XSLT processors have an API that allows you to pass a DOM as a parameter, at the very least. Saxon also allows you to pass a StreamSource, but I don't expect that's universal.

Comment: And at the very least, you could add a URIResolver and have it pass in the stream you want when a "special" URI is used.